# Way to allow SPECIFIC users to talk to one and other individually on a wix website

Tags: web-apps, chat

I run a mental health charity. We pair clients to coaches for free mental health support. I'd like for coaches and clients to be able to correspond, exclusively with the people they've been paired with, via a web app. Wix allows embedding of javascript, so I'm pretty sure this is possible but I'm not sure how best to go about it.